# Модуль ocstore 2.3 для вывода изображений

Tags: php, opencart, модули, ocstore

Суть в том, что на ocstore нужен модуль, который будет удобен заказчику для управления из админки; Модуль ищу такой:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**а)** модуль, который будет выводить изображения в виде плитки/сетки

**б)** на фото первая плитка, находится в состоянии hover и только в этом состоянии должны показываться информация, заголовок и кнопка перейти в каталог --- так вот данные при наведении должны редактироваться в админке

Есть такой модуль для **ocstore**?

Comment: А чем стандартный "html содержимое" модуль не подходит? Один раз шаблон сделать, а потом Ctrl+C/Ctrl+V

Comment: @AndrewHobbit каким образом заказчик сможет управлять этим содержимым потом без знания кода?